# How to list projects for particular user

Tags: gerrit

We have our company users list and with that users list we need to prepare a report that each user have access to which gerrit project.

So how to list the project(s) for particular user from gerrit?

Some direction to achieve this will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to give a try:

1. Use the "gerrit ls-projects" SSH command

Using the "--has-acl-for GROUP" option, you can list projects on which access rights for this group are directly assigned. Note: projects which only inherit access rights for this group are not listed:

```
ssh -p 29418 USER@GERRIT-SERVER gerrit ls-projects --has-acl-for GROUP
```

See more details in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-ls-projects.html).

2. Use the "Check Access" project REST endpoint

Using this endpoint you can verify if a user has access to a repository. Note: this requires the View Access global capability:

```
curl --user USER:PASS --request GET "https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/projects/PROJECT/check.access?account=ACCOUNT-ID&ref=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster"
```

This command checks if the user with the ACCOUNT-ID number has access to the branch "master" of the PROJECT. As you have noted, you need to know the user ACCOUNT-ID. You can find the user ACCOUNT-ID using REST too:

```
curl --user USER:PASS --request GET  "https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/accounts/?q=username:USERNAME" | sed 1d | jq --raw-output .[]._account_id
```

See more details in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#check-access).

Comment: I am using second option, `Check Access` rest api returns `)]}'
{
  "status": 200
}`  `View Access Global capability permission enabled`. Still something i m missing? please confirm.

Comment: No, it's everything correct. The answer {"status": 200 } means the user has access to the repository, otherwise, the answer would be {"message":"user ACCOUNT-NUMBER cannot see project PROJECT","status":403}.

Comment: Oh yes. i have read the document again. Thanks a lot Marcelo.